# How to know if files have been changed?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I'm writing a custom C++ program that copies files only if they were changed in the source since the last time they were copied. So I need to know if files in my specific folder were changed.

I was originally thinking about calculating SHA-1 hash on those files, but then this probably means that I have to do this on the entire folder. Plus, what if the size of those files is 100GB. That would mean that I have to calculate SHA-1 on 100GB of data that would probably take some time.

So I'm curious if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: This may be better suited to Programmers SE, I'm not sure.

Comment: Two options:
1) Windows keeps a timestamp for when the last change was made.
2) .NET has `FileSystemWatcher`, you can try to find the Win32 API equivalent.

Comment: The timestamp can be modified without changing the file.

Comment: @MasterMastic: The Win32 equivilents are `FindFirstChangeNotification()`, `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`, and `SHChangeNotifyRegister()`.

Comment: Thank you, guys. The issue is that my app may not be running when the change occurs. It may be over a week span or more. Would those APIs still catch it then?

Comment: The hash doesn't work anyway. Two different files can have the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of possibilities.

One would be to use [NTFS change journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363803.aspx) to track what files have been modified.

Each file also has an "archive" flag associated with it. This is typically used by backup programs. Any time you write to a file, the flag is set. When you copy/back it up, you clear the flag. When you want to see what files to copy/backup, you just check whether the flag is set or clear. Obvious problem: collisions with other backup programs.

There is also a `ReadDirectoryChangesW`<sup>1</sup>. This, however, can only detect changes that happen while your code that uses it is running. So, to use it to track changes you need to do something like setting up a service that runs in the background all the time to keep track of changes. Depending on the file and how it gets modified, it's still possible for even this to miss changes that happen during boot (before your service starts executing).

I've listed these in roughly descending order of how well they seem to fit your needs--i.e., change journals are almost certainly the best fit, the archive flag second and `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (by quite a large margin) the worst fit for your apparent needs.

---

<sup>1. There's also an older `FindFirstChangeNotification`/`FindNextChangeNotification`, but they're less versatile and have all the same shortcomings as `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. At one time they were useful for code that needed to be compatible with Windows 95/98/SE (since those didn't include `ReadDirectoryChangesW`) but it's been years since there was a good reason to use them.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the info. Unfortunately the API method won't work since my app may not be running when the change occurs. So I'm curious about the "archive" and "modified" flags. Is it something that I can get via `GetFileAttributes`? If so, do I need NTFS file system. Will it work with, say, FAT-32?

Comment: The archive flag has been around nearly forever (all the way back to FAT-12 under MS-DOS). Yes, you can retrieve it with `GetFileAttributes` or just about anything else that reads a file's attributes (e.g., `FirstFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`).

Answer (score 1):

In comments for other answers, you've stated that you can't use a file-monitoring API (such as  FindFirstChangeNotification) since your code may not be running at the time the change occurs.

I would suggest a multi-pronged approach.

1. If your application is running, use the file monitoring APIs to detect new changes.
2. On startup or when a new disk appears, check to see if the file size is the same as before. If it isn't, then you know you have a change.
3. If the file size is the same, you could use the file's archive flags to determine if it has changed. However, the archive flag is easily altered by users and therefore you probably shouldn't rely on it.
4. Use the file's last altered timestamp. This can be modified by users, but it's more difficult to do.
5. Use a hash to determine if the file has changed. The hash you pick depends on how important it is to detect changes. If it isn't critical something like CRC32 or MD5 would be sufficient. If it needs to be secure, consider SHA-256. Consider breaking large files into chunks. That way you don't have to hash the whole file before getting a "this changed" result.

This tiered approach lets you skip the expensive hashing whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in "real-time", Windows has a native API for that. [FindFirstChangeNotifcation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)